# How to add Tooltip Functionality to X-axis labels in canvajs?

Tags: javascript, canvas, tooltip, canvasjs

How to add Tool-tip functionality to x-axis labels? Here is my code

```
window.onload = function() {
var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
    title: {
        //text: "Line Chart"
    },
    axisY2: {
        includeZero: false,
        title: "Accuracy"
    },
    axisY: {
        title: "Speed"
    },
    data: [{
        type: "line",
        name: "Average Speed(in sec)",
        showInLegend: true,
        dataPoints: [
        {
            label: 'Test1 simple test simple test ',
            y: 3
        },
        {
            label: 'Test2',
            y: 5
        },
        {
            label: 'Test3',
            y: 6
        },
        {
            label: 'Test4',
            y: 4.5
        },
        {
            label: 'Test5',
            y: 6.8
        },
        {
            label: 'Test6',
            y: 7.9
        },
        {
            label: 'Test7',
            y: 8
        },
        {
            label: 'Test8',
            y: 4.5
        }, ]
    },
    {
        type: "line",
        name: "Accuracy(in %)",
        showInLegend: true,
        axisYType: "secondary",
        dataPoints: [
        {
            label: 'Test1',
            y: 50
        },
        {
            label: 'Test2',
            y: 60
        },
        {
            label: 'Test3',
            y: 99
        },
        {
            label: 'Test4',
            y: 78
        },
        {
            label: 'Test5',
            y: 56
        },
        {
            label: 'Test6',
            y: 44
        },
        {
            label: 'Test7',
            y: 67
        },
        {
            label: 'Test8',
            y: 70
        }, ]
    }, ]
});
chart.render();
}
```

When the labels are too long It doesn't look as per my test. So I want to add specified content to the label and when user hovers over the label, I want to show full label in toolTip.